# React Native: Calling a function that's inside a functional component from a class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm lost on how functional components and class components interact. How do I call a functional component's function from inside a class?

I'm trying to call Initialize()

App.js:

```
import Firebase from './components/Firebase';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
  // Call Initialize()
  }
```

Firebase.js:

```
const Firebase = () => {
   
  
  const Initialize = () => {
   // Initialize Firebase
   
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

      console.log("Firebase is initialized");
  }
}

export default Firebase;
```

Comment: Your second example is not a functional component. It does not return any JSX. If you clarify your intention here it will be easier to get helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the confusion is more related to JavaScript than any JavaScript library/framework.
You are trying to call a private function, only available in the Firebase closure function.
If you want to set available the Initialize function, like a "static" method, declare it as property:

```js
const Firebase = () => {
   ...
};
  
Firebase.Initialize = () => {
   // Initialize Firebase
   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

   console.log("Firebase is initialized");
};

export default Firebase;

// and then

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Firebase.Initialize()
  }
}
```

Comment: Another option is to make `Firebase` ***not*** a function, but rather an exported object, which is essentially what you did by appending it to the default export object.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to say: "Another option is to make Firebase not a component"? And yes, that's right, but i don't know all the Firebase object scope (maybe it's a component?).

Comment: I don't know, author wrote `I'm lost on how functional components and class components interact.`. `Firebase` could be a HOC, providing a store provider, or any kind of context, who knows?

Comment: This is why I asked a question in the question comments. Right now, it is not a component, it is just a function. If so, no need to write a static method. But, as you said, "who knows?".

Comment: To hopefully clarify, I'm attempting to make a .JS that will handle all the Firebase initialization and storage. It will not need to render anything, I just need to be able to call the functions within it from any component to store in the server.

Comment: So you should create and helper, or a service, or anything else, not related to a React component, and import it, call it, as normal JavaScript.